# Analytic function with 2 different bounds in the unit circle, find a bound for $f(0)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is

Let $f$ be analytic on the unit disk, satisfying $\left|f(z)\right| \leq 18 $ on Re$(f) > 0, \left| z \right| = 1$ and $\left|f(z)\right| \leq 2$ on Re$(f) < 0, \left| z \right| = 1$.

Show that $\left| f(0)\right| \leq 6$.

**My idea**

Use Cauchy's integral formula,

$$
2 \pi \left|f(0)\right| = \left| \int\limits_{\left| z\right| = 1, Re(z) > 0} \frac{f(z)}{z} dz + \int\limits_{\left| z\right| = 1, Re(z) < 0} \frac{f(z)}{z} dz  \right| \leq \int\limits_{\left| z\right| = 1, Re(z) > 0} 18 \, d\left| z\right| + \int\limits_{\left| z\right| = 1, Re(z) < 0} 2 \, d\left| z\right| = 20 \pi. 
$$

So I get $\left| f(0) \right| \leq 10$, not $6$.

I tried to get a counterexample to see if the question was wrong, the only function that I could find was $f(z) = 6 (3^z)$, which is exactly $6$ on $f(0)$, so no luck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* The function $g(z) = f(z)f(-z)$ satisfies $|g(z)| \le 2 \cdot 18 = 36$ everywhere on the boundary of the unit disk.

Comment: Ok, so we apply maximum principle and we get $\left| f(0)\right|^2 \leq 36$, I'm just commenting to say that the hint answers the question.